# Iterate for each item in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I think I am missing something simple here.

In my controller I have

```
public ActionResult ListPage()
    {
        return View(db.Sections.OrderBy(x=>x.Order).ToList());
    }
```

On the ListPage.cshtml I have

```
@model IEnumerable<Section>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(item => item, "SectionTemplate")
}
```

And in the Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SectionTemplate.cshtml I'm not sure what to put. Ideally this view would look like

```
@model Section
<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```

But a little more robust obviously.
When I do that, I get an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Section]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Section'.

How can I change this code to access the properties on the individual model in the template?

Thanks!

Comment: does it work without DisplayFor in your ListPage view?

Comment: As in does the ListPage view show up? Yes it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, inside of the lambda, `item` resolves to the parameter of said lambda, and not the `item` declared in the outer scope. Just rename the parameter of your lambda and it should work as expected:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(_ => item, "SectionTemplate")
}
```